# How to make own version of wc utility?

Tags: wc

Do you know how to make your own wc utility or any tutorials which will help you make one. We have to make our own wc utility for school which:
-uses command line options
-reading text from file
-counting the number of characters, words and lines in the file, 
-using fork() to create child processes

I just want to say I dont want anyone to do it for me just assist me on where i can get help.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful example is probably the solution provided in "The C Programming Language" by K&R. There is also a ready solution [here](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/examples/wc.html) (done in C, with literate programming).

It is beyond me why you would use fork() to create child processes. What for?